# What is the most logical way to store multiple versions of a database in a SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, replication

We operate a website in AWS that uses Azure as the data source. Azure is populated by transactional replication from our customers. Once every 3 or 4 months a new version of the customer database is released. My company does not make this customer database. More often than not, the new version does not come with an update script and basically all the customer information is wiped and the new database version is a fresh create.

How do I maintain an uninterrupted history in the cloud through these updates? I see only two options: create a new database for each version, create a new schema for each version. The first will get expensive over time, the second feels hacky. If it's such a big deal should I just make my own update scripts?

Comment: ... what's wrong with the drop/create of the database?  Is there information you've previously added that you want to persist?  Do you need to be able to access the old database while moving things to the new database?  What actually changes - just the data, or are there schema changes as well?

Comment: Sorry, "uninterrupted history" is unclear. Yes, I want to keep all the old data. Columns are added/removed/updated, and tables are added/removed/updated. We want to provide at least a year's worth of data, and with unreliable upgrade paths this is an interesting challenge for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep expense down, consider Elastic Pools for your Azure SQL DBs. Elastic pools have an allocation of eDTU's that can be shared between N databases as needed. As long as the sum total of DTU's used by all databases in the pool do not exceed the max DTU's for the pool, you're golden.

I assume that older versions of your database need to be accessible, but probably don't have much (or any) traffic. By hosting older versions in the same elastic pool, you can drastically reduce cost and still have them accessible if needed.

The other option would be to take backups of older versions, then restore them if ever needed.

Comment: The only thing I am worried about is our database limit. On our current plan, we get 500 databases. We are using the Elastic Pools, for exactly the reasons you have listed. Depending on how many bad update scripts I am provided with, a customer can use 3 or 4 databases per year. I understand this might just be a reality the business has to face, I just want to use the best solution.